# Convert array of strings into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have this JavaScript array:

```
[ "124857202", "500255104", "78573M104" ]
```

I want to convert this particular array into an array of objects as shown below:

```
[
  { name: "124857202" },
  { name: "500255104" },
  { name: "78573M104" }
]
```

Comment: Since it was confusing for some people, I changed the format into valid JavaScript, instead of copy-pasted console outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach - `Array#reduce`.

```js
var arr = ["124857202", "500255104", "78573M104"];
var res = arr.reduce(function(s, a){
    s.push({name: a});
    return s;
  }, [])
  
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The array given by OP is a simple array of string. He showed us the output of Firefox's Variable View when debugging via Firefox's Web Console (or Chrome's)...

Answer (score 14):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each value into a different value:

```
var newArr = arr.map(function(value) {
  return {name: value};
});
```

`Array#map` applies the callback to each element in the array and returns a new array containing the return values of the callback.

Comment: @Kinduser: The OP has an array of strings and wants an array of objects. You are starting with an array of objects.  The result you producing is also different from what the OP wants. It seems you are misinterpreting the console output in the question.

Comment: I was trying to do this myself with arrow functions, but was getting back `undefined` . TIL that returning object literals in arrow functions need to be wrapped in parentheses, like `arr.map(value => ({ name: value }))`

Comment: @Danny: Yep, otherwise `{...}` denote the *function body*.

Answer (score 6):

I would take a look at the [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function in javascript.

```
const mappedArr = arr.map(value => {
  return {
    name: value
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to **convert this particular array** into an array of objects as
> shown below

If you want to change the actual array in place (rather than creating a new array), you can use a for loop to iterate the indexes of your array. For each index, you can replace the value with an object `{name: arr[i]}`. This object has a `name` key, and takes a value which is the current element `arr[i]`.

```js
const arr = [ "124857202", "500255104", "78573M104" ];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = {name: arr[i]};
}
console.log(arr);
```

Or, if you want to make a new array and leave the original untouched, you can use [Felix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681987/5648954), here it can be re-written to use more modern ES6 features to make it more concise, such as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015):

```js
const arr = [ "124857202", "500255104", "78573M104" ];
const res = arr.map(name => ({name}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["124857202", "500255104", "78573M104"];
var arrayOfObjects = [];

arrayOfStrings.forEach(function (element, index) {
   arrayOfObjects.push({
        name: element,
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Felix Kling' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681987/1166087), [gehsekky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42682012/1166087) and the second part of [Nick Parsons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808475/1166087) are the most correct. For completeness, here is a version that uses Underscore's [_.map](https://underscorejs.org/#map):

```
import { map } from 'underscore';
var result = map(array, name => ({name}));
```

For this particular use case, `_.map` doesn't buy you much compared to `Array.prototype.map` except for a little bit of added portability. Going the other way, however, is a bit easier on the brain with `_.map` because of Underscore's iteratee shorthands:

```
// Underscore map
var array = map(result, 'name');

// Array.prototype.map
var array = result.map(obj => obj.name);
```

Underscore's `map` and other collection functions really shine when you need to iterate over a plain object, since JavaScript's built-in methods don't support this at all:

```
var objectOfStrings = {
    first: "124857202",
    second: "500255104",
    third: "78573M104"
};

// to array of strings, Underscore
var arrayOfStrings = map(objectOfStrings);

// to array of strings, vanilla JS
var arrayOfStrings = [], value;
for (key in objectOfStrings) {
    arrayOfStrings.push(objectOfStrings[key]);
}

// to array of objects, Underscore
var arrayOfObjects = map(objectOfStrings, name => ({name}));

// to array of objects, vanilla JS
var arrayOfStrings = [], name;
for (key in objectOfStrings) {
    name = objectOfStrings[key];
    arrayOfStrings.push({name});
}

var objectOfObjects = {
    first: {name: "124857202"},
    second: {name: "500255104"},
    third: {name: "78573M104"}
};

// to array of strings, Underscore
var arrayOfStrings = map(objectOfStrings, 'name');

// to array of strings, vanilla JS
var arrayOfStrings = [], value;
for (key in objectOfObjects) {
    arrayOfStrings.push(objectOfObjects[key].name);
}

// to array of objects, Underscore
var arrayOfObjects = map(objectOfObjects);

// to array of objects, vanilla JS
var arrayOfObjects = [], value;
for (key in objectOfStrings) {
    arrayOfObjects.push(objectOfStrings[key]);
}
```