# How do I incorporate the index of an array while defining a property of said array within a class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, indexing, properties

Sorry if the title makes no sense.. let me explain

Say I have the following 2d array.. the first array representing ice cream and the second representing milkshakes

```
menu = [ ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'almond'],
         ['vanilla', 'pineapple', 'strawberry'] ]
```

Now I create a class that takes this array as input

```
class cafe{
  constructor(menu){
    this.iceCreams = menu[0]
    this.milkshakes = menu[1]
  }
}
```

Now I want to define a property called 'price' for each flavor of milkshake.

`this.milkshakes[n].price =  < a function that computes price based on value of n >`

so that i can access them like this :
`cafe.milkshakes[0].price`

So how do I incorporate the index 'n' of the array while defining the property

I haven't tried anything bcos I dont know how to even approach this ☹️

Comment: The index is already available to you since it's an array, what's missing is the `price` property, you'll need your milkshake elements to be objects, not just strings ie `[{flavor: 'vanilla', price: 2.5},]`

Comment: see: [Convert array of strings into an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681952/convert-array-of-strings-into-an-array-of-objects) for a place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in your constructor.

You can grab the names, and call `map` function on it and do whatever you want. Please check the following example. There, `calculatePrice` is a function that takes the index and returns the price based on the index.

```
class Cafe {
constructor (menu) {
    this.iceCreams = menu[0].map((flavor, index) => {
      return {
        flavor,
        price: calculatePrice(index)
      }
    });

    this.milkshakes = menu[1].map((flavor, index) => {
      return {
        flavor,
        price: calculatePrice(index)
      }
    });
}
```

This is a minimal answer.

UPDATE:
For a detailed and improved answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/cafe-example-wxp2c4

Comment: Good idea! It could be improved with a `class Milkshake`

Comment: @NishchalBhat If this worked for you, don't forget to upvote and mark this as the correct answer :) If you need to improve this, let me know. I can help :)

Comment: @SennenRandika I 'accepted' the answer but it says I need at least 15 reputation to upvote

Comment: @NishchalBhat No worries. Accepting is important :)  BTW, if you need some detailed and improved answer, please check the sandbox here. :) https://codesandbox.io/s/cafe-example-wxp2c4

Answer (score 1):

So, in the `milkshakes` array you need each item as an `object` data structure, not a string.

```
menu = [ ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'almond'],
         [{ flavor: 'vanilla' }, { flavor: 'pineapple' }, { flavor: 'strawberry' }] ]
```

and then you can loop through and set the price, something like this.

```
menu.milkshakes.forEach((item, index) => item.price = index))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use objects:

```
menu = [
  [
    {
      name: "vanilla",
      price: 200,
    },
    {
      name: "chocolate",
      price: 200,
    },
    {
      name: "almond",
      price: 200,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      name: "vanilla",
      price: 200,
    },
    {
      name: "pineapple",
      price: 200,
    },
    {
      name: "strawberry",
      price: 200,
    },
  ],
];
```

and then:

```
class cafe{
  constructor(menu){
    this.iceCreams = menu[0]
    this.milkshakes = menu[1]
  }
}
```

now iceCreams and milshakes have the property price and name

example:

```
iceCreams[n].price
iceCreams[n].name
```