# Converting an array of strings into an array of objects with key value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the following array of strings `string[]` to an array of objects with the following format `[{"title": value "value": value }]`

This is the array I get

```
locationQuery = [
  "Antwerpen",
  "Hemiksem",
  "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat",
  "Antwerpenplein, Gent",
  "Antwerpenstraat, Bredene",
  "Antwerpenstraat, Oostende",
  "'s-Herenstraat, Antwerpen",
  "'t Berkenveld, Antwerpen",
  "'t Doolhofje, Antwerpen",
  "'t Duivelshoekje, Antwerpen"
]
```

and this is the format I would like to convert it to

```
[
  {title: "Antwerpen", value: "Antwerpen"},
  {title: "Hemiksem", value: "Hemiksem"},
  {title: "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat", value: "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat"}
  ...etc
]
```

Looking at other SO answers and I'm trying to use reduce, but I'm only getting the very last value from that array in `{}`.

For example  when I do

```
      locationQuery.reduce(
        (a, v) => ({ ...a, ['title']: v, ['value']: v }),
        {},
      ),
```

I get the following:  `locationQuery {title: "'t Duivelshoekje, Antwerpen", value: "'t Duivelshoekje, Antwerpen"}`

What I would like is the format:

```
locationQuery= [
  {title: "Antwerpen", value: "Antwerpen"},
  {title: "Hemiksem", value: "Hemiksem"},
  {title: "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat", value: "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat"}
  ...etc
]
```

Comment: honestly, I would just loop through your array and create a new array with the data you want.

Comment: use map instead you are trying to create an object here `locationQuery.map(x => ({title:x,value:x}))
 `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726504/js-convert-array-of-strings-to-array-of-objects         
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681952/convert-array-of-strings-into-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @Rick and @cmgchess thanks of course I could have used `map` don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks.

I'm marking @InSync as the answer because his/hers/their/them answer was correct as well and it was posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an object and overload its `title`/`values` properties with new values. What you need is return an array and add a new object to it in every iteration:

```js
const locationQueryArray = locationQuery.reduce(
    (previous, current) => [...previous, { title: current, value: current }], []
);
```

Also, `Array#map` is preferred in this particular situation where new elements can be mapped from original ones:

```js
const locationQueryArray = locationQuery.map(
    element => ({ title: current, value: current })
);
```

```js
const locationQuery = [
  "Antwerpen",
  "Hemiksem",
  "Antwerpenlei, Brasschaat",
  "Antwerpenplein, Gent",
  "Antwerpenstraat, Bredene",
  "Antwerpenstraat, Oostende",
  "'s-Herenstraat, Antwerpen",
  "'t Berkenveld, Antwerpen",
  "'t Doolhofje, Antwerpen",
  "'t Duivelshoekje, Antwerpen"
];

const locationQuery_reduce = locationQuery.reduce(
  (previous, current) => [...previous, { title: current, value: current }], []
);

const locationQuery_map = locationQuery.map(
  element => ({ title: element, value: element })
);

console.log(locationQuery_reduce, locationQuery_map);
```

Comment: thanks for making me understand a bit more about reduce as well